# Setting a date in session.createDateTime to a specific d/t and time zone

Tags: javascript, xpages

I am trying to set a NotesDateTime object to a specific time GMT and have the following formula:

```
var blankDT:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("01/01/1970 0:0:0 AM GMT");
```

When I run this it returns a null date time. I have tried formating the date string as "1970:01:01:0:0:0 GMT"

When I look at the help in the designer it is pretty unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was not extracting the correct portion of the resulting date. This works

```
var blankDT:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("1970/01/01 0:0:0 AM GMT");
viewScope.put("vsBlankDate",blankDT.getGMTTime());
```

Comment: Remember, date format is specific to regional settings of server/client the code runs on. So to hardcode date format is troublesome in some regions.

Comment: and don't forget to  .recycle()

Comment: I use this as a fixed date. and store it in a date Array. I consider this date to be a null or blank date to hold the place in the Array. Then when I output the date Array in a view or computed field I check to see if the date is my blank date (adjusting for local time). My background code will replace the 'blankDate' with 'now' when specific actions are taken. When displayed if the value is blankDate I display a "-" if not I display the formated date using the proper local settings. And yes I recycled blankDate.